# PHPmailer mail send with cc recieved in bcc. How to overcome with this?

Tags: php, email

i am sending mail with phpmailer. all mails are sent but one recipient is in cc but when he recieved a mail he recieved that mail in bcc.

here is my code for send email

```
$mail->AddAddress(test@test.com,SUPPORT_SHORTNAME);
$mail->AddCC(test2@test.com);
```

Guys you can see here i am sending mail to two recipient.but when mail is recieved to test2 its goes to bcc.

so can anyone tell me why this problem is created.i am using gmail smtp setting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is that working you don't have `'` or `"` quotes around the email addresses ?

Comment: thats already working but i had add second address to cc but its recieved as bcc. and in my originall code i had add the variable so there is no need of qoutes. so i am forgot to add quote here